# Migrate DDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I want to migrate the dyanmodb table to another dynamodb table (in same account) but by changing the structure/schema of the data. What are best options in doing this ?

I searched for data migration options but the possible options AWS Glue and import/export data to S3 suggestions work for same data schema

Answer (score 1):

If by changing the structure/schema you simply mean that you want to change the keys, then using [export/import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3forDynamoDB.html) is the best option by far, from both a cost and operational overhead point of view.

If you need to do aggregations or any transforms on the data, use [AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/what-is-glue.html), it provides in memory processing which you can use Spark to transform the data. Glue also has [DynamoDB connectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb) and works seamlessly for reading and writing to DynamoDB.